# Send data per mail

Tags: xcode, email, uitextfield, iboutlet, mail-sender

I'm working on an app but I'm missing a small part. I prepared a View so that you can insert data into UITextField and I can then send this information via email. I tried many ways.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RMAcpu : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> 
@property  IBOutlet UITextField *prodotto;
@property  IBOutlet UITextField *seriale;
@property  IBOutlet UITextField *cfiva;
@property  IBOutlet UITextField *email;
@property  IBOutlet UITextField *problema;
- (IBAction)inviodati:(id)sender;
@end
```

Regarding the .m, I tried this but don't send the information. can you help me to sending information by email?

```
#import "RMAcpu.h"

@interface RMAcpu ()

@end

@implementation RMAcpu
@synthesize prodotto;
@synthesize seriale;
@synthesize cfiva;
@synthesize email;
@synthesize problema;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setProdotto:nil];
    [self setSeriale:nil];
    [self setCfiva:nil];
    [self setEmail:nil];
    [self setProblema:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)inviodati:(id)sender {
    NSString *stringaMail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:cristian@prokoo.com", [[prodotto text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], [[seriale text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], [[cfiva text]  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringaMail]];



}
@end
```

Comment: I removed the Italiano which serves to nothing here, but please can you precise what's the question/problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an e-mail directly from your app, unless you implement your own SMTP client. A current project that follows this approach is [skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/).

If you do not want to try it this way, you will need to use the [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) from the `MessageUI` framework. This will allow you to create an email template and to prefill fields like recipient, subject and message body, but the user will have to tap the send button manually.

Comment: i'm trying with the apple sample

Comment: i have resolved with MFMailComposeViewController: 

[mail setMessageBody:@"PRODOTTO: \n\nSERIALE: \n\nCF/P.IVA: \n\nEMAIL: \n\nSPECIFICARE IL PROBLEMA: \n\n\n\n1. Danni da caduta\n2. Eventuali sigilli rotti\n3. Viti forzate" isHTML:NO];